# ASP.NET MVC4 Debug Mode can't be enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I can't figure out why I can't enable the debug mode. I have a website on the production server. Everything was working fine locally but now I get this error message on production which I need to solve :

> Security Exception
>       Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed 
>       by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission 
>       please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust 
>       level in the configuration file.
>
> Source Error:
>
> The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when 
>       compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps,
>       then request the URL:
>
> 1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated 
>      the error. Example:

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
```

> or:
>
> 2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application 
>       to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular
>       file to be compiled in debug mode.

The problem is that my web config files already contains :

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    Many other stuff here...
</system.web>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you logged in as administrator? Is visual studio running from administrator account?

Comment: Locally yes. But I get this message on the production server, not on my computer. Everything is working fine locally.

Comment: Did you deploy debug binaries on produiction?

Comment: Hum, yes I think so... The compilation profil is still set to "Debug" in VS so I guess that I published the debug binaries... I completely forgot to change that. Is that  the cause of the problem which is preventing me from activating the debug mode ?

Comment: Your debug web.config may contain the `<compilation debug="true" />` flag, but by default the release web.config transformations remove this line, meaning it may not be in the web.config on the production server. At any rate, I would suggest using ELMAH or another error logging utility on your production server.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've been able to solve the problem. I used the empty project template when I created the project. It tried to use the Basic Template and to copy and paste all my files but the configurations files and it worked. Perhaps the Empty template misses some assemblies or lines in the web config file. Now it's perfectly working on the production server, however what I don't undersand is why my project was working without any problem locally even with the Empty Project Template.